# Binding a listbox to an observable collection - running out of ideas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an observable collection in my window class that I want to be able to bind to a listview in the xaml. I have been googling around for the best part of an hour and a half now and all I can seem to come up with as a response is "Wow, why does it have to be so mental?"

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this, my collection is called "TestItems", and a test Item has two variables - "name" and "type" - both strings.

I would like to display all of the "name" properties of the TestItems in my observable collection...

Any help appreciated, I have even managed to mock this up with C++ and Qt in a matter of minutes, yet it seems to elude me in C# right now.

Current xaml :

```
<ListBox Name="ItemsOfData" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="name" 
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
</ListBox>
```

Current C# code :

```
public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItems = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItems = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this.ItemsOfData;

        TestItem test = new TestItem("name", "type");

        this.TestItems.Add(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you have right now?

Comment: Is it setup in the mvvm pattern? Where are you creating your collection of test items? In the code behind? Or in a ViewModel?

Comment: it's not such difficult, however I have to agree that many things in `WPF` are so quite strange and that's why it has a very steep learning curve, a newbie has to work hard even he is a pro in some other field.

Comment: this.DataContext = this;  And you need to have a get on TestItems to make it a public property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can only bind to a public property
Need a get to make it a public property
And need to fix the DataContext

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<TestItem> testItems = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItems { get { return  testItems ; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
        this.DataContext = this;    
        TestItem test = new TestItem("name", "type");    
        this.testItems.Add(test);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s simple.  As long as you have your collection is something like this in a viewmodel or in the code behind and you add items to that collection:

```
   private ObservableCollection<TestItem> _TestItems;
   public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItems
   {
   get { return _TestItems;}
   set 
       { 
          _TestItems = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("TestItems");
       }
}
```

If you are using a viewmodel, then you need to set the datacontext in the constructor of the window code behind to:

```
 //substitute with whatever your viewmodel class name is
DataContext = new ViewModel()
```

And in your xaml like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
this.DataContext = this.ItemsOfData;
```

to this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

You have set the wrong context. You can use the `Output` window to detect errors in the bindings.